# Specifying "Up The Tree" Haskell Modules

Tags: haskell, module, hierarchy

My understanding is that the dotted syntax of modules, in Haskell, represents logical structure on disk. So, if we have a structure like this:

```
Main.hs
Foo/
  Bar.hs    -- exports "Bar"
  Quux.hs   -- exports "Quux"
```

...then in our `Main.hs`, we can do:

```
import Foo.Bar
import Foo.Quux
```

(I assume we can only have modules at leaf nodes of the filesystem. For example, in the above, there's no way we could have a `Foo` module, as well.)

In this example, we're traversing down the tree. What happens if we want to go up?

```
lib/
  SomeModule.hs
  XYZ.hs
src/
  Main.hs
```

That is, in `Main.hs`, how do we import `SomeModule` or `XYZ`?

Maybe this wouldn't be a common occurrence with `Main`, but what about inter-module dependencies? They could legitimately need to reference "cousin" nodes.

Comment: It's very common to have modules at "branches" -- just e.g. create ```Foo.hs``` in the same directory as your ```Foo/``` dir

Comment: Also, to be precise: the dotted syntax of modules represents logical structure on disk *in GHC*. The Report itself gives no indication of how modules are stored on disk at all, and a rival implementation could choose to do other things -- have a manifest file, use a database, store things in the cloud...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the fully qualified name of the module and tell GHC where to find the root of the module hierarchy with the `-i` option. In your example, this means that you should use `import XYZ` in `Main.hs` to import the module and the command `ghc -i../src --make Main.hs` to compile your program. If you need to compile mutually recursive modules, take a look at [this section](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#mutual-recursion) of the GHC manual.

If you're using Cabal to build your package, you can group the modules under `lib` in a library and then make that library a dependency of your executable. You will have the following directory structure:

```
some-package.cabal
lib/
  XYZ.hs
src/
  Main.hs
```

The relevant parts of the `some-package.cabal` file will look like this:

```
Name: some-package
Version: 1.0
...
Library
    ...
    Exposed-modules: XYZ
    Hs-source-dirs:  lib
    ...
Executable some-executable
    ...
    build-depends: some-package == 1.0
    ...
...
```

This is especially useful if your package includes a test or benchmark suite, because the modules under `lib` will be compiled only once.

Here's [a real-life example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-parmake-0.1.8/ghc-parmake.cabal) of this technique.