# ghc --make module hierarchy

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to build a standalone program for the first time in Haskell, and am having trouble figuring out how to get ghc --make working with the directory organization of my liking. As the moment I have the following tree:

```
readme.md
src/
  Main.hs
  Ciphers/
    Affine.hs
    Shift.hs
    Substitution.hs
  Tests/
    HCTests.hs
```

With the following imports:

Main.hs:

```
 module Main where

 import Tests.HCTests
 import Ciphers.Affine
 import Ciphers.Shift
 import Ciphers.Substitution
```

HCTests.hs

```
module Tests.HCTests (unitTests) where

import Ciphers.Substitution
import Ciphers.Affine
import Ciphers.Shift
```

Affine.hs

```
module Affine (
  affineEnc,
  affineDec,
  ) where
```

Shift.hs

```
module Shift (
  shiftEnc,
  shiftDec
  ) where

import Affine
```

Substitution.hs

```
module Substitution (
  substitutionEnc,
  substitutionDec,
  ) where
```

Based on this - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Standalone_programs - It seems to me the following command should at least properly handle the imports in main, although I'm unclear whether the imports in HCTests will work (it seems to me if I read this properly - [Specifying "Up The Tree" Haskell Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273289/specifying-up-the-tree-haskell-modules) - they should).

The command, which I run in the base directory, is:

```
ghc -O2 --make -i src -o crypto Main.hs
```

Fails with error:

```
target `src' is not a module name or a source file
```

**Edit**

I have an additional question. Thanks to Zeta's answer, I've got that sorted, however when I run it, I get the following error:

```
src/Ciphers/Substitution.hs:5:8:
    File name does not match module name:
    Saw: `Substitution'
    Expected: `Ciphers.Substitution'
```

So my assumption is that I'd solve this via:

Substitution.hs

```
module Ciphers.Substitution (
  substitutionEnc,
  substitutionDec,
  ) where
```

My question is how then can I handle that Shift.hs needs to import Affine.hs, while I still want both Ciphers.Shift and Ciphers.Affine?

Comment: As Zeta's answer points out, there was a typo in the Wikibook. It is now fixed.

Comment: Actually, it looks like import Ciphers.Affine inside of Shift.hs works. It was throwing an error earlier when I was trying to simply compile Affine.hs earlier without make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not separate the command line option `-i` and the search path with whitespace, since `-i` with following whitespace *resets* the [search path](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#search-path).

Use

```
ghc -O2 --make -isrc -o crypto Main.hs
```

or

```
ghc -O2 --make -i./src -o crypto Main.hs
```

instead.

Comment: never mind, I have an edited question I'll append to the main one, this comment isn't working.

Comment: @JackGibbs: If the edit changes your question significantly, it's usually a better idea to post a new one. But we'll see after the edit.

Comment: @JackGibbs Your module names should match the directory structure, and so they should be `Ciphers.Affine`, `Ciphers.Substitution`, etc.

Comment: I don't think it does all that much, it's along the same lines (and I think fits under the same title), and in fact gets right at duplode's comment.